# (Bash) echo not output stored variables

Tags: bash, sh

I'm new with bash and doing my first steps in it 
I want to learn How to store argument localy in script for later use and wrote this script

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":d" opt;do
     case "${opt}" in
         d)
           d =$OPTARG
           echo "-d was triggered ! storing ${d}" >&2
           ;;
     esac
done
```

this is my output :

```
$ -d was triggered! storing
```

what is my problem? : I don't store the data correctly or I don't print it correctly or both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `:` after option name in `getopts` command :

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "d:" opt; do
     case "${opt}" in
         d)
           d="$OPTARG"
           echo "-d was triggered ! storing ${d}" >&2
           ;;
     esac
done
```

You also need to remove the spaces around `=` and better to use quotes in assignment.

Now when you run:

```
./script.sh -d 1234
-d was triggered ! storing 1234
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was missing !!

Answer (score 2):

Remove whitespace before `=$OPTARG`. Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thanks ! but @anubhava's answer is closer to solve my problem